# How do I view individual memory blocks on my PC?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, ram

Details:  When I first started programming and was being taught about pointers and references I remember a lecturer opening a detailed window/view that showed the individual memory blocks, it kind of looked like a spreadsheet

does anyone know how to get this view?

['Memory blocks' may not be the right term.]

Further Details / Already Attempted:
I have been unable to find this through googling as I just get endless results on how to check my memory with the Performance tab in Task Manager.

I couldn't find a way to see the view I'm talking about in either event viewer or task manager.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you can look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2022)

Comment: You can do this, but only within a given process. Remember, [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) is *substantially* different from physical memory.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

If you are using Visual Studio you can look at this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2022

Thanks [Raffallo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11424134/raffallo) !

Comment: Recommendation: summarize the contents of the page at the link so that users in the future have some hope of using this answer after the link rots.